# Pivot SSRS Dataset

Tags: sql, matrix, reporting-services, dataset, pivot

I have a dataset which looks like so

```
ID  |       PName       |       Node        |       Val             |
1   |       Tag         |       Name        |       XBA             |
2   |       Tag         |       Desc        |       Dec1            |
3   |       Tag         |       unit        |       Int             |
6   |       Tag         |       tids        |       100             |
7   |       Tag         |       post        |       AAA             |
1   |       Tag         |       Name        |       XBB             |
2   |       Tag         |       Desc        |       Des9            |
3   |       Tag         |       unit        |       Float           |
7   |       Tag         |       post        |       BBB             |
6   |       Tag         |       tids        |       150             |
```

I would like the result in my report to be

```
    Name    |   Desc    |   Unit    |   Tids    |   Post    |
    XBA     |   Dec1    |   int     |   100     |   AAA     |
    XBB     |   Des9    |   Float   |   150     |   BBB     |
```

I have tried using a SSRS Matrix with

```
Row: PName
Data: Node
Value: Val
```

The results were simply one row with Name and next row with desc and next with unit etc.  Its not all in the same rows and also the second row was missing. This is possibly because there is no grouping on the dataset.

What is a good way of achieving the expected results?

Comment: *I didn't quite get the expected results*  What results did you get?  What is not right about them?  What would you like to see instead?

Comment: Also, where is your original dataset coming from?  Is that the result of a query you have already written but not included here or is that how your data is stored in your database?  At present, I cannot see a reliable way to turn your dataset in your question into your desired format, as there is nothing grouping your `Name, Desc, unit, tids, post` values.

Comment: Hi great question, the data is coming from a Stored Procedure however there are other reports which are also based on this stored procedure. I just do not want to duplicate this stored procedure.  Yes there is no grouping. Only similarity is the ID column 1,2,3,6,7 and it repeats.

Comment: Then this is impossible.  Without being able to reliably tell the query engine that the second instance of `ID = 7` belongs to the second instance of `ID = 2` you cannot get your desired output.

Comment: I assume that `PName` really isn't `Tag` for every row? Perhaps it changes for each "grouping" of values?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this for a production scenario but if you need to knock out a report quickly or something you can try this. I would just not feel comfortable that the order of the records you get will always be what you expect.

You COULD try to insert the results of the SP into a table (regular table, temp table, table variable...doesn't matter really as long as you can get an identity column added). Assuming that the rows always come out in the correct order (which is probably not a valid assumption 100% of the time) then add an identity column on the table to get a unique row number for each row. From there you should be able to write some math logic to "group" your values together and then pivot out what you want.

```
create table #temp (ID int, PName varchar(100), Node varhar(100), Val varchar(100))

insert #temp exec (your stored proc)

alter table #temp add UniqueID int identity

then use UniqueID (modulo on 5 perhaps?) to group records together and then pivot
```